# Iterate over specific rows, sum results and store in new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` in which I have already defined rows to be summed up and store the results in a new row.

For example in Year 1990:

| Category | A | B | C | D | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | 147 | 78 | 476 | 531 | 1990 |
| F | 914 | 356 | 337 | 781 | 1990 |
| G | 117 | 874 | 15 | 69 | 1990 |
| H | 45 | 682 | 247 | 65 | 1990 |
| I | 20 | 255 | 465 | 19 | 1990 |

Here, the rows G - H should be summed up and the results stored in a new row. The same categories repeat every year from 1990 - 2019

I have already tried it with `.iloc` e.g. [4:8], [50:54] [96:100] and so on, but with iloc I can not specify multiple index. I can't manage to make a loop over the single years.
Is there a way to sum the values in categories (G-H) for each year (1990 -2019)?

Comment: This is the purpose of the function [`.groupby(['Year'])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) have you take a look at it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the `multiple index` what you mean.

It usually appear after some `group` and `aggregate` function.

At your table, it looks just `multiple column`

So, if I understand correctly.

Here a complete code to show how to use the multiple condition of `DataFrame`

```py
import io

import pandas as pd

data = """Category  A   B   C   D   Year
E   147 78  476 531 1990
F   914 356 337 781 1990
G   117 874 15  69  1990
H   45  682 247 65  1990
I   20  255 465 19  1990"""

table = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter="\t")

years = table["Year"].unique()
for year in years:
    row = table[((table["Category"] == "G") | (table["Category"] == "H")) & (table["Year"] == year)]
    row = row[["A", "B", "C", "D"]].sum()
    row["Category"], row["Year"] = "sum", year
    table = table.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in G/H, you can slice with `isin` combined with boolean indexing, then `sum`:

```
df[df['Category'].isin(['G', 'H'])].sum()
```

output:

```
Category      GH
A            162
B           1556
C            262
D            134
Year        3980
dtype: object
```

*NB. note here the side effect of `sum` that combines the two "G"/"H" strings into one "GH".*

Or, better, set Category as index and slice with `loc`:

```
df.set_index('Category').loc[['G', 'H']].sum()
```

output:

```
A        162
B       1556
C        262
D        134
Year    3980
dtype: int64
```